# How can I access my REST resource with wildfly?

Tags: java, rest, jakarta-ee, wildfly

Hi I am developing a Rest API with IntelliJ following [the official doc](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-running-your-first-restful-web-service-on-glassfish-application-server.html).

But I am getting an 404 Not found error while accessing to the resource... I can still access the index.jsp page. I followed every step from de doc but I am using Wildfly instead of Glassfish.

Here is the resource :

```
@Path("devices")
public class DevicesResource {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String getAllDevices() {
        return "Hello world from thingsplay.";
    }

}
```

Here is the Application child class :

```
@ApplicationPath("/api/v2.0")
public class ApplicationConfig extends Application {

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        Set<Class<?>> resources = new HashSet<>();
        addResourceClasses(resources);
        return resources;
    }

    public void addResourceClasses(Set<Class<?>> resources) {
        resources.add(be.thingsplay.resources.DevicesResource.class);
    }

}
```

So when I access http://localhost:8080/api/v2.0 I get the index page but when I try to access http://localhost:8080/api/v2.0/devices I get an 404 Not Found error.

When I looked at the artifact I noticed that the jersey library wasn't included in the war. But when I try to add it to the war I get exceptions when I try to deploy the application.

[image]

The exceptions I get :

```
14:57:23,799 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "apirest_war_exploded.war" (runtime-name: "apirest_war_exploded.war")
14:57:24,147 WARN  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYWELD0013: Deployment deployment "apirest_war_exploded.war" contains CDI annotations but no bean archive was not found. (No beans.xml nor class with bean defining annotations)
14:57:24,178 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 89) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./apirest_war_exploded: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./apirest_war_exploded: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/base/Function
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:85)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/base/Function
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.ServiceFinder.<clinit>(ServiceFinder.java:165)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.internal.ServletContainerProviderFactory.getAllServletContainerProviders(ServletContainerProviderFactory.java:66)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.init.JerseyServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(JerseyServletContainerInitializer.java:132)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:186)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:171)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:42)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:234)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:100)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:82)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.base.Function from [Module "deployment.apirest_war_exploded.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:198)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:363)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:351)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:93)
    ... 21 more

14:57:24,182 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (management-handler-thread - 20) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "apirest_war_exploded.war")]) - failure description: {
    "WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./apirest_war_exploded" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./apirest_war_exploded: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/base/Function
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/base/Function
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.base.Function from [Module \"deployment.apirest_war_exploded.war:main\" from Service Module Loader]"},
    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./apirest_war_exploded"],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => undefined
}
14:57:24,183 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (management-handler-thread - 20) WFLYSRV0021: Deploy of deployment "apirest_war_exploded.war" was rolled back with the following failure message: 
{
    "WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./apirest_war_exploded" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./apirest_war_exploded: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/base/Function
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/base/Function
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.base.Function from [Module \"deployment.apirest_war_exploded.war:main\" from Service Module Loader]"},
    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./apirest_war_exploded"],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => undefined
}
14:57:24,207 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYSRV0028: Stopped deployment apirest_war_exploded.war (runtime-name: apirest_war_exploded.war) in 23ms
14:57:24,208 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (management-handler-thread - 20) WFLYCTL0183: Service status report
WFLYCTL0184:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
      service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./apirest_war_exploded (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."apirest_war_exploded.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
WFLYCTL0186:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./apirest_war_exploded

[2017-07-14 02:57:24,302] Artifact apirest:war exploded: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.
[2017-07-14 02:57:24,302] Artifact apirest:war exploded: java.lang.Exception: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./apirest_war_exploded" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./apirest_war_exploded: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/base/Function
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/base/Function
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.base.Function from [Module \"deployment.apirest_war_exploded.war:main\" from Service Module Loader]"},"WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./apirest_war_exploded"],"WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => undefined}
```

Comment: try to use `/` in the path `@Path("/devices")`

Comment: The currently posted exception stacktrace is a red herring, since it is caused by incorrectly bundling libraries you don't need to bundle. Please reverse that and instead post the logging of the deployment where you can't access the resource.

Comment: @tima I already tried, it doesn't change a thing.

Comment: @Gimby There is no error logged when I get the 404 Not Found error.

Comment: I did not ask for an error, I asked for the logging.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you do not need to add any REST implementation jars (such as Jersey) to your application because Java EE 7 servers such as WildFly and GlassFish come with this for free.

The crux of your problem is that your URLs are missing the context path of your application (which is `rest_glassfish_hello_world_war_exploded` in the tutorial that you referenced).

ie. the correct service URL should be something like:

> http://localhost:8080/rest_glassfish_hello_world_war_exploded /api/v2.0/devices

where `rest_glassfish_hello_world_war_exploded` should be replaced with your actual application name if it's different.

Comment: Well, I have access to the index.jsp with http://localhost:8080/api/v2.0.

Comment: Did you explicitly configure your app to be accessible from the root "/" context?